# function onClick() - cart not adding - what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

I have a product page on Shopify with an Add to Cart button.

On click, the product gets added to cart and page redirects to another upsell product.

After they add upsell product to cart, it goes to checkout page BUT it's only displaying the upsell product and not the first product user wanted to buy. What's wrong with the code below?

How do I make both products appear in checkout?

```
<script>
function redirectToUpsellPageHandler(wrapper) {
  var upsellPageUrl = '/clientproducts/cryogenic-storage';
  var addToCartButton = wrapper.querySelector('.sqs-add-to-cart-button');
  var productVariants = wrapper.querySelector('.product-variants');

  if (addToCartButton) {
    addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  }

  function isVariantInStock() {
    return productVariants.getAttribute('data-variant-in-stock');
  }

  function onClick() {
    if (productVariants && isVariantInStock() || !productVariants) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.location.href = upsellPageUrl;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}

function redirectToUpsellPage() {
  // Product Page
  var productPage = document.querySelector('.collection-type-products.view-item');
  if (productPage) {
    redirectToUpsellPageHandler(productPage);
  }

  // Product Blocks
  var productBlocks = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.sqs-block-product'));
  productBlocks.forEach(redirectToUpsellPageHandler);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', redirectToUpsellPage);
window.addEventListener('mercury:load', redirectToUpsellPage);
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure 1000ms (1 second) is enough time for Squarespace to run it's own functions and add the product to cart? My experience is that Squarespace can be quite slow to respond to this action in some cases. If you set it to 3000ms and it works, the either keep the time relatively high or setup a mutation observer on `.sqs-add-to-cart-button` and listen for the class to be added to it: `.cart-added`

Answer (score -1):

Add some console.logs and make sure you're getting into your onClick function. If you're not there may be some type of issue with using a function named onClick since that is a reserved function in jQuery or JS.